# Chrome extension infinite loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an infinite loop that I do not understand

```
function bot(cartInfo, tab) {
    function injector(file, message) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: file, runAt: 'document_end'}, function(r) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message, function(result) {
            });
        });
    }

    //this section gets repeated over and over
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
        function myListener(tabId, changeInfo, updateTab) {
            injector('addToCart.js', cartInfo.sizeInfo);
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(myListener);  
        } 
    );

}
```

I want it to enter the addListner section call the injector( which runs another file addToCart) once and return and exit.  If I remove the line chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(myListener);  It will work but calls the injector function infinitely.  If I keep the line it exits the loop, but does not execute the injector.   Is there a way to get around this? or  a way to remove the listener while inside the addToCart file so I know it has been executed at least once?

Comment: How do you know it's an infinite loop and just not getting triggered by a lot of tab updates?

Comment: i placed a counter inside the block and it keeps keeps going.  I'm not updating the tab.  Would there be any reason the tab would change so rapidly without any action?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe `executeScript` causes  `onUpdated` events to trigger and that's what's causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Could it be that the `bot` function is executed more than once ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend having the `removeListener` within the callback it's removing. I think if you refactor the code a little you should be able to get it to work. This makes the listener method more explicit and moves the `removeListerner` to trigger at the end of `injector` method.

```
function bot(cartInfo, tab) {

    var myListener = function(tabId, changeInfo, updateTab) {
        injector('addToCart.js', cartInfo.sizeInfo);
    }

    function injector(file, message) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: file, runAt: 'document_end'}, function(r) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message, function(result) { });
        });
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(myListener);
    }

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(myListener);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work this way either, and I don't know how to step through these extensions so I can't figure out where its going wrong.  thanks for trying

Comment: Here are some good docs for stepping through JS with the Chrome Dev Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints

Comment: @abraham: I don't see anything bad with removing the listener from within the listener callback itself. It is a standard technique and makes perfect sense for listeners that only need to be triggered once.